# file path in iOS 6 gives me null

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsfilemanager

I'm using iPhone6 simulator, I'm trying to get a file (any extension pdf of html) by using any of this codes:

```
 NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", documentName] ofType:nil];
```

or

```
NSString *file2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:@"pdf"];
```

I'm sure that the file in exists in Resources folder and I'm not add the file, I download it from web programmatically and see it in this path 
( /Users/myMac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.9/Applications/E60F22DD-7301-48EF-AB25-B9D42FA6AD49/myApp.app) I see the file, but the code does not see it

but this codes sometimes gives me null and some other times gives me the file.

Why is this happen and how to prevent this and make it always gives me the file. 
consider that I uses

```
if(file != nil)
```

and want to make if file == nil try to open it by using any way.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your file is added to project's target. Choose your target then Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources. The file should be there.

Sometimes it's worth cleaning your project and building from scratch. I have seen cases when file added wasn't copied to simulator/device until clean was performed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not exactly copy the file to my resources, the file is downloaded from web to the Resources by code and I want to open it, when I check resources in /Users/myMac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.9/Applications/E60F22DD-7301-48EF-AB25-B9D42FA6AD49/myApp.app  I see the file, but the code not see it

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, you download it in the app? If yes then you can only put it inside app's Documents folder. In such case you should be using something like this `NSString* filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@.pdf", documentName]];` to get proper path because your file won't be in app's main bundle.

Comment: I downloaded it in mainBundle using this code  `NSString *pdfPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] ,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",documentName]];`

   `[data writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];` and trying to get it by the code that in question. I wrote Nslog to insure that it gets the file path, sometimes it prints the path and other times not print it. :S

Comment: You shouldn't be even trying to put anything in this path, everything your app downloads should go to Documents folder.

Comment: But if I used Documents folder, Will anyone be able to see the files in my project? I mean that I'm not want anyone to easily take pdf files from my project. Sorry I'm new in iPhone.

Comment: Documents directory of your app is protected by system. That means no other app running on device can see it's content.

Answer (score 0):

a) If you download anything from the web then the content goes to the document directory of your application.

b) No other application can interact with the your application doc directory.

c) The Bundle path i.e. the groups and files section of your application is read only.

d) No one can sneak your applications PDF unless and until you have allowed access to the document directory of your application.

Hope this helps